# Magento 2.3 Product Category not showing changes on frontend

Tags: magento2, category, layout, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I am wondering if anyone can help.

I have made some design changes to the following category: https://www.valvesonline.co.uk/manual-valves/ball-valves.html

However these changes do not appear on the front end. The category title and description should be in the left hand column and the top image shouldn't even be showing. I am using layout update XML to make the changes and know it works, as I have made the changes to all other categories and they work fine.

I have cleared the cache, disabled and re-enabled the category and double checked but it isn't working.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: have you checked if default store is selected ??

Comment: Great suggestion, I actually just selected the store it was part of and noticed that category wasn't pulling the default settings through and got it fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Great!! You can answer your own question so that it may help other people as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have this one figured out.

On the categories admin page, I changed the Store View from **All Store Views** to the store in question, selected the category with the problem and noticed that the category settings were not selected to **use default value**.

Selecting the options to use default value works.

Hope this might help anyone experiencing a similar problem, just double check on the store view.

Comment: "Hope this might help anyone experiencing a similar problem, just double check on the store view." - it sure just helped me! Thanks for posting your solution. We had a few set up by different team members who may or may not have started by changing the scope.

Answer (score 0):

After all the above process if it doesn't work go to system-> cache management->flush static Cache files don't freak out if interface changes, just do the same  system-> cache management->flush static Cache files. interface will be back. Reload crtl+F5 on the browser and the changes will be visible. This process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still struggling after applying all the answers above. Check if flat table for categories is enabled. If yes, you need to re-index "catalog_category_flat" after clearing the cache.

Flat table configuration is located under: *Shops -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog*